# PHP spam redirect script is not working, but only displays plain html

Tags: php

I've written the following code following in an attempt to end the seemingly unending onslaught of spam.  I'm using a list of keywords that I found in another article related to the same issue; however that author was coding for a different architecture.  I'm writing for PHP on IIS7.  The problem is that when the code does pick up on a spammy referrer instead of the visitor being redirect to 127.0.0.1 as I'd like done, the page is being rendered as plain text with the guts of the page visible.   Here is the code:

```
<?php
$strReferrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$strFilterKeywords = array("Uggboots", "porn", "pharma", "viagra", "vuitton", "jerseys", "handbags", "sleep-deprivation", "sleep-disorders", "insomnia", "phentermine", "phentemine", "vicodin", "hydrocodone", "levitra", "hgh-", "-hgh", "ultram-", "-ultram", "cialis", "soma-", "-soma", "diazepam", "gabapentin", "celebrex", "viagra", "fioricet", "ambien", "valium", "zoloft", "finasteride", "lamisil", "meridia", "allegra", "diflucan", "zovirax", "valtrex", "lipitor", "proscar", "acyclovir", "sildenafil", "tadalafil", "xenical", "melatonin", "xanax", "herbal", "drugs", "lortab", "adipex", "propecia", "carisoprodol", "tramadol", "porno", "shemale", "gangbang", "-cock", "-anal", "-orgy", "cock-", "anal-", "orgy-", "singles-christian", "dating-christian", "cumeating", "cream-pies", "cumsucking", "cumswapping", "cumfilled", "cumdripping", "krankenversicherung", "cumpussy", "suckingcum", "drippingcum", "pussycum", "swappingcum", "eatingcum", "cum-", "-cum", "sperm", "christian-dating", "jewish-singles", "sex-meetings", "swinging", "swingers", "personals", "sleeping", "libido", "grannies", "mature", "enhancement", "sexual", "gay-teen", "teen-chat", "gay-chat", "adult-finder", "adult-friend", "friend-finder", "friend-adult", "finder-adult", "finder-friend", "discrete-encounters", "cheating-wives", "housewives", "/-sex/", "xxx", "snowballing", "fat-", "-fat", "diet", "pills", "weight", "supplement", "texas-hold-em", "poker", "casino", "blackjack", "mortgage", "refinancing", "cash-advance", "cash-money", "pay-day", "netwasgroup.com", "nic4u.com", "wear4u.com", "foxmediasolutions.com", "liveplanets.com", "aeterna-tech.com", "continentaltirebowl.com", "chemsymphony.com", "infolibria.com", "globaleducationeurope.net", "soma/125mb.com", "mitglied/lycos.de", "foxmediasolutions.com", "jroundup.com", "feathersandfurvanlines.com", "conecrusher/org", "sbj-broadcasting.com", "edthompson.com", "codychesnutt.com", "artsmallforsenate.com", "axionfootwear.com", "protzonbeer.com", "candiria.com", "bigsitecity.com", "coresat.com", "istarthere.com", "amateurvoetbal.net", "alleghanyeda.com", "xadulthosting.com", "datashaping.com", "zick/biz", "newprinceton.com", "dvdsqueeze.com", "xopy.com", "webdevboard.com", "devaddict.com", "eaton-inc.com", "whiteguysgroup.com", "guestbookz.com", "webdevsquare.com", "indfx.net", "snap/to", "2y.net", "astromagia/info", "free-sms");
foreach ($strFilterKeywords as $strFilter) {
    if stripos($strReferrer, $strFilter) !== false
        {
        Header("Location: http://127.0.0.1");
        }
    }
unset($strFilter)
?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Jason

ANSWERED>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Before I could approve the answer the person who provided a working solution rescinded his post; however for the benefit of others I'd like his response to be visible.  Below is the code he suggested:

```
<?php
$strReferrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$strFilterKeywords = array("Uggboots", "whiteguysgroup.com", "guestbookz.com", "webdevsquare.com", "indfx.net", "snap/to", "2y.net", "astromagia/info", "free-sms");
foreach ($strFilterKeywords as $strFilter)
{
    if( stristr($strReferrer, $strFilter) ) // wrap the if statement in ( ) - use stristr function 
        {
        header("Location: http://127.0.0.1");
        }
}
unset($strFilter); // end ;
?>
```

To whoever this mystery answer-er was I send my sincere thanks!

Jason

Comment: Are you sure PHP works on top of your IIS7? Have you tried that code with xampp, or on a real LAMP server?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
 Header("Location: http://127.0.0.1");
```

to eg

```
 Header("Location: http://google.com");
```

to see if the issue is your script. It look OK to me though. If the 'guts of the page' is rendered (I assume you mean the php code) it indicates a config issue with your server, i.e. it's not interpreting PHP but serves it as plain text.